# Using js load in same php file

Tags: javascript, php, integrate

```
<script>
 setInterval(function(){
         $.ajax({
               url :'user_online.php',

               success: function()
                   {
                       $('.chat-o').load('user_online.php');
                   }
            });
     },1000); 
</script>
```

Let's say I have this script. How do I make it work if user_online is the file I put this in (meaning, how can I make this script work internally-- within a php file called the same as the url)

Basically I want to apply the same thing as above to another page make it auto display the results without having to reload it:

```
<?php 
   $gameid = fetchinfo("value", "info", "name", "current_game");
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `id` < $gameid ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
while($rowd=mysql_fetch_array($query)):
  //define stuff
  $lastwinner=$rowd["userid"];
  $winnercos =$rowd['cost'];
  $winnerpercent = $rowd['percent'];
  $winneravatar=fetchinfo("avatar", "users", "steamid", $lastwinner);
  $winnername = fetchinfo("name", "users", "steamid", $lastwinner);
  $steamlink = fetchinfo("steamprofile", "users", "steamid", $lastwinner); ?>
  <div class="cont row">
  <div class="col-xs-24 header">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-24 body">
  <div class="col-xs-16 col-sm-16">
  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href=<?php echo $steamlink; ?> class="img hidden-xs">
  <img src=<?php echo $winneravatar; ?> > </a>
  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href=<?php echo $steamlink; ?> class="name"> <?php echo $winnername; ?> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="right text-right">
  <span class="win">
  Win: <span>$ <?php echo round($winnercos, 3); ?> </span></span>
  <span class="chance">
  Chance: <span><?php echo round($winnerpercent, 2); ?>% </span> </span> </div> </div>
```

Updated it with what I wanted. Can anyone tell me if it's ok? This is from one part of index.php

```
 <div class="site history col-xs-24 col-sm-18 col-md-14 col-lg-12"> <h2>History</h2> <div id="history">
  <script>
 setInterval(function(){
         $.ajax({
               url :'index.php',

               success: function()
                   {
                       $('.history').html(data);
                   }
            });
     },1000); 
</script> 
   <?php 
   $gameid = fetchinfo("value", "info", "name", "current_game");
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `id` < $gameid ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
while($rowd=mysql_fetch_array($query)):
  //define stuff
  $lastwinner=$rowd["userid"];
  $winnercos =$rowd['cost'];
  $winnerpercent = $rowd['percent'];
  $winneravatar=fetchinfo("avatar", "users", "steamid", $lastwinner);
  $winnername = fetchinfo("name", "users", "steamid", $lastwinner);
  $steamlink = fetchinfo("steamprofile", "users", "steamid", $lastwinner); ?>
  <div class="cont row">
  <div class="col-xs-24 header">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-24 body">
  <div class="col-xs-16 col-sm-16">
  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href=<?php echo $steamlink; ?> class="img hidden-xs">
  <img src=<?php echo $winneravatar; ?> > </a>
  <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href=<?php echo $steamlink; ?> class="name"> <?php echo $winnername; ?> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="right text-right">
  <span class="win">
  Win: <span>$ <?php echo round($winnercos, 3); ?> </span></span>
  <span class="chance">
  Chance: <span><?php echo round($winnerpercent, 2); ?>% </span> </span> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already used ajax to do something in `user_online.php`, so need to load the data again in `.load()`. So

Change this,

```
success: function(data)
     {
         $('.chat-o').html(data);
     }
```

If you are using only php in `user_online.php`, make sure you `echo` the values.

Comment: What errors? The first code part was just an example of how I want it to look like but with self load from same file. The thing is I want to apply that to the 2nd code part

Comment: Errors for what? I do not have any errors. Ok so, what I want is to make the second code automatically update without having to reload the page. Just ignore the first code box.

Comment: What ever you have tried is correct. just replace that `success()` with what ever i have given.

Comment: Also replace chat-o with a different id if my current <div id="history"> right? Also the php file is called index.php

Comment: The id which you have changed now, should be the place where you want to display data without reload.

Comment: Ok and the whole code with the <script> tag should be before or after the <?php tag? Or it doesn't make any difference

Comment: make sure you add it after including jquery files.

Comment: Ok. ;LAST QUESTION: I'm using bootstrap 3, so basically I have all these pages that pop out of nowhere. So doing the code for just one div id  (ie: history in this case) will show only the results from the php code from that id right?

Comment: Ya... And that will be coming from your pho file which u have given in url for Ajax

Comment: This is a gif of the java page I want to apply this on https://gyazo.com/f10a35ac5068eece2c6fa4576c23a945

Comment: what you can do is , load the content on page load and play with display none or block(if content is static). If content is dynamic, on click, call ajax and add the content to div with some `id` or `class`

Comment: Ok I did the update. Also updated my post. Please check if I did it right :D. Thank you very much!

Comment: it is not auto updating

Comment: then ?? nothing is hapenning??

Comment: It's just showing like before. So I have to reload page all the time to show the results

Comment: see console for any errors in ajax. may be some syntac errors will be there.

Comment: are you able to see ajax call in console?? keep `alert(data)` inside `success()`, see what is getting alerted.

Comment: im talking about browser console?? which browser u use??

Comment: I have chrome browser.

Comment: press F12, u can see network section there, just see there for errors.

Comment: see this, check any one of them. you will underatans, https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+check+ajax+call+in+chrome&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=2to5VpvvEpLI8Af_m4HQBg

Comment: you have to read error one by one and start fixing each one. Then only ajax will work

Comment: you have missed something, see my code for `success: function(data)`, you have missed `data` there.

Comment: still there r so many errors in console. you have to fix them.